# How to improve query suffering index problem in MariaDB

Tags: indexing, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and suffering index problem.

here is information about table.

| column | type |
| --- | --- |
| col1 | varchar(10) |
| col2 | timestamp(6) |

Query

```sql
select col1 from table where col1 is not null and col2>='2022-04-10 00:00:00' and col2<'2022-04-11 00:00:00' group by col1;
```

i set index option in both of columns.

but, when i see execution plan about my query, 'Using index' is never seen in extra field.

give me a help.

Comment: can you share your table fields and index definition?

Comment: How big is the sample data you are using in  your tables? Does the time range specified cover < 25% of the rows in the table? Can you show the explain? A query will generally use only one index. Take a read through [this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#indexing).